# Client error: (400) Bad Request when URL provided from a variable

Tags: r, google-api, httr, google-url-shortener

I am trying to shorten several thousands of URLs using Google API. I am using httr to do POST. Whenever I provide a URL to post as a variable I get "Client error: (400) Bad Request" but when the same URL is provides directly as string (for example "http://www.google.com") everything works fine. A minimal example is provided below:

```
library(httr)
library(httpuv)

# enter data
mydata <- data.frame(Link = "http://www.google.com")

# 1. Find OAuth settings for google:
#    https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp
oauth_endpoints("google")

# 2. Register an application at https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
myapp <- oauth_app("google", key = "key goes here", secret = "secret goes here")

# 3. Get OAuth credentials
google_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google"), myapp, scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener")
```

**This returns Error: client error: (400) Bad Request**

```
req <- POST('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id',
       add_headers("Content-Type"="application/json"),
       body='{"longUrl": mydata$Link[1]}', config(token = google_token))
stop_for_status(req)
```

**This works just fine**

```
req <- POST('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id',
       add_headers("Content-Type"="application/json"),
       body='{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com"}', config(token = google_token))
stop_for_status(req)
```

I tried encoding URLs, testing both http and https and but none of the above seem to have any effect. Could anyone provide me with any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

-jacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First: data frames coerce character vectors to factors:

```
mydata <- data.frame(link = "http://www.google.com")
class(mydata$link)
#> [1] "factor"

mydata <- data.frame(link = "http://www.google.com", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
class(mydata$link)
#> [1] "character"
```

Second, you're sending `'{"longUrl": mydata$Link[1]}'` to google - i.e.
the longUrl you are submitting is `mydata$Link[1]`, not
`http://www.google.com`. It's easiest to fix that by using `jsonlite` to
do the encoding:

```
req <- POST('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id',
  body = list(longUrl = jsonlite::unbox(mydata$link[1]),
  encode = "json",
  config(token = google_token)
)
stop_for_status(req)
```

(Unfortunately the `unbox()` is necessary because jsonlite defaults to
converting length-1 vetors into js arrays, not scalars.)

Comment: Thank you Dr. Hadley! This definitely clarifies things! I loaded the jsonlite package and replaced
"body = list(longUrl = jsonlite::unbox(mydata$link[1])}"
with
"body = list(longUrl = jsonlite::unbox(mydata$link[1])),"
[replaced closing curly bracket with matching regular bracket and added a comma.]

jsonlite::unbox(mydata$Link[i]) returns a scalar with the long URL but I am getting Error 400. The req element lists reason: badContent - Unsupported content with type: multipart/form-data. I am quite sure that this has something to do with the curly bracket but can't seem to see why :-(

Comment: Maybe you need a more recent version of httr?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was running current version of httr but an older version of R (3.0.1). After updating R everything works great. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the class of mydata$Link[1] is incorrect, it gives factor but probably should be character.

```
class(mydata$Link[1])
vec<-as.character(mydata$Link[1])
```